# Search in a list of files

Tags: search, full-text-search, grep, cscope

I have a huge list of C source and header files, actually an autogenerated "cscope.files" file.

Is there a way to search for a string(not a C symbol) in all those files?

The files are distributed in a huge networked filesystem and I do not want to grep recursively in the root of that system.

I use Red Hat Enterprise Linux and gvim(+cscope) for my development. Any vim or python(2.3) or shell solution is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.c'|xargs grep "some string"
```

Comment: actually
    cat cscope.files | xargs grep "string"
solved my problem. thanks.